# Matplotlib more than 3 lines on same axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do you get matplotlib to display more than 3 plots on the same figure?
For example I have:

```
plt.figure(1)
th=np.linspace(0,pi,num=200)
y=range(10)
for i in range(10):
    alph=np.exp(i/2)
    y[i]=((np.cos(alph*np.cos(th)) - np.cos(alph))/np.sin(th))**2
    figure(1)
    plt.plot(th/pi,y[i])
plt.show()
```

But I can't get the figure to display more than 3 lines at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me when I comment out the line #figure(1)

```
import numpy as np 
import pylab as plt 
from math import *
plt.figure()
th=np.linspace(0,np.pi,num=200)
y=range(10)
for i in range(10):
    alph=np.exp(i/2)
    y[i]=((np.cos(alph*np.cos(th)) - np.cos(alph))/np.sin(th))**2
    plt.plot(th/pi,y[i],  label = 'Line %d' %i)
plt.legend(loc =2)    
plt.show()
```

Comment: Woops sorry it works, I just couldn't see more than 3 plots because their powers were too low

Answer (score 1):

This should work, otherwise check your matplotlib version (this works with 1.4.3)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import *

plt.figure(1)
th=np.linspace(0,pi,num=200)
y=range(10)
plots_y = []
for i in range(10):
    alph=np.exp(i/2)
    y[i]=((np.cos(alph*np.cos(th)) - 1. * np.cos(alph))/np.sin(th))**2
    plots_y.append(y[i])

for plot in plots_y:
    plt.plot(1. * th/pi, plot)
plt.show()
```